# QGIS - How to select features in a given order

Tags: python, select, qgis

First of all, thanks for your time!

So, I have a group of some features like the image:
[Group of Features in Vector Layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpsWa.png)

I want to select all of them, but in a particular order, for example, in a clockwise-like pattern, starting from the right-top most one, going down, then left, going up and the last one is the middle one from the first "row": [Clockwise Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SIl3.png)

I used the "Features from polygon" selection tool: [Features From Polygon Selection Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd4iI.png) in the order explained above.
Then, I ran a simple script in the Python terminal:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
selection = layer.selectedFeatures()
for feature in selection:
    print(feature.id())
```

And got as result:

```
>>> exec(open('/tmp/tmpwkso5fxd.py'.encode('utf-8')).read())
-27
-28
-29
-30
-31
-32
-33
-34
-35
-36
-37
-38
-39
-40
-41
```

Then I deselected all of the features, and made another polygon select, again in a clockwise pattern, but starting from the left top-most feature, going right, then down, then up until I reached the first, like this: [Clockwise selection starting in another feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HviAc.png)

I then ran the same script, and got the exact same result. The order was unchanged.

Is there a selection tool, plugin or a selection algorithm that I can use to select features in the order the user draws the polygon/line?

I thought of something like create points from mouseclicks, then create lines from them, and populate this lines with points using GRASS' v.to.points, but I couldn't manage to get mouseclicks stored in an ordered list.
I also thought of raytracing, or Unity's Raycast, but I don't know to implement things like that... And this could also be a bit of overkill...

Again, thanks for your attention!

Have a nice day! =)

Comment: Maybe this can help - however, you should adapt the expression: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/408986/88814